# WordPress : i changed front-page template and it gives me 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, server

I need immediate help regarding WordPress website. i had to make some changes to the home  page so i just download front-page template and what i did is made some changes just moved some blocks up and some of them down and reuploade the template now  site is not loading itself . there is a 500 error on the server please need you help immediately what has happened

```
Server error

500
```

Comment: Best thing to do is undo whatever you have just done, then you can investigate what may have caused the issue.

Comment: i did but that did not help me

Comment: Have you updated any plugins or wordpress at all?

Comment: not at all  i just worked with some html and thats it .added some bootstrap classed and thats t

Comment: That's weird, could you send me a link to the front-page template php file at all?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the debug option true `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);` to know the exact issue .

Another thing to make sure is ,have you changed its file permission ?
Apply 755 permissions on that template and check

Answer (score 0):

just try to check your file permission that you have been uploaded after changes , if nothing happens , just change the front page from dashboard of your site 
go to setting->reading and change the front page , , i hope it will help you ,,,